# How to delete app scores with "app access_token"?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I am not good at English. Sorry for that~

Here is my code for deleting app scores. 
I am using this facebook game tutorial [ios-friend-smash](https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-friend-smash)

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"APP_ID/scores"] parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"DELETE" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
```

When I am trying to build and run, I am getting the below error.

```
error code 400 :This method must be called with an app access_token.
```

but it succeeded in getting the score to send the score.

How do I clear the score using `APP_ACCESS_TOKEN`?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete a user's scores in the following way:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"me/scores"]
                             parameters:params 
                             HTTPMethod:@"DELETE" 
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, 
                                          id result, NSError *error)
```

You would not need to provide an app access token. It would instead use the currently logged in user's access token.

See also: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/scores/

If you instead want to delete all the scores for your app, then yes, you would need to call the APP_ID/scrores endpoint. Since you'd need an app access to do this, don't call it from the iOS app. The app access token should only be used in a server environment so it's secure.